# Can't make action calls through anaconda py35 env in spark HdInsight

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

As per the documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation

we had installed several external python modules through new anaconda env 'py35_data_prof'. However as soon as we invoke any rdd action calls like rdd.count() or rdd.avg() in our python code, spark2 throws -

```
Cannot run program "/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35_data_prof/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Y2HH.png)

FYI, The python indicated in error path - '/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35_data_prof/bin/python' is actually a symlink rather than python dir.
I have been looking up the HDInsight docs but can't seem to find the fix. Please let us know if there is a way around it.

Comment: use Ambari to check the Python path used and then used that path to install the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The error message “`Cannot run program "/usr/bin/anaconda/envs/py35_data_prof/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory`” clearly says the unable to find/locate the package installed. Make sure the package is installed with the all the requirements mentioned below.

•   Create Python virtual environment using conda.

•   Install external Python packages in the created virtual environment if needed.

•   Change Spark and Livy configs and point to the created virtual environment.

I would request you to follow the each and every step mentioned here: “[Safely install external Python packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation#safely-install-external-python-packages)”.

Hope this helps.